# split reading sensors values from stream after it via xbee

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I'm trying to make project to monitor my home. I am using some gas sensors and temperature and humidity sensors. I want to do this wirelessly and I think the 
best thing to do that is XBee.

I use this code for the transmitter Arduino:

```
char dataPacket[64];

int gx = 1;
int gy = 321;
int gz = 456;
int ax = 654;
int ay = 789;
int az = 987; 
int mx = 147; 
int my = 258; 
int mz = 369;

void setup(){

 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop(){





   sprintf(dataPacket, "X%d" ,gx);
    //  sprintf(dataPacket, "A%dB%dC%dD%dE%dF%dG%dH%dI%d", gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, mx,     my, mz);
Serial.println(dataPacket);


    }
```

gx gy gz .... these are the sensor reading variables

and in the receiving Arduino I use this code

```
void setup(){
    // Start up our serial port, we configured our XBEE devices for 9600 bps.
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{

    if(Serial.available() > 0)
{
     while(Serial.available() > 0)
 {
        char dataPacket[64];

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
  dataPacket[i] = Serial.read();
 Serial.print(dataPacket[0]);

}

String show = Serial.readStringUntil('C') ;
delay(500);

}
}
}
```

but i can't split the values from the stream and put them into their variables (gx gy ...)

Does anyone have idea how to split it?

Answer (score 2):

Try a communication protocol with a `,` as a delimiter like:

```
messageId,data1,data2,data3,....,dataN\n
```

And use the `Messenger` library to parse it.

See my answer on comms protocols here:

[Communication Protocol Best Practices and Patterns](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/communication-protocol-best-practices-and-patterns/4222#4222)

An how to use the `Messenger` library here:

[Send Processing color data into Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/send-processing-color-data-into-arduino/4527#4527)

Comment: You may be able to use sscanf() which works like a backward sprintf(), to assign the values from the input string into each variable.